# Why NSRegularExpression does not match when heading quote?

Tags: regex, swift4.2

Here is the whole sample which should match:

```
   let input = "L’iPhone XR serait un topselling (des prévisions de vente en hausse de 50% avant même sa sortie)"

   let pattern = "\\b(iPhones?(\\s*(se|X((s(\\s*Max)?)|r)?|\\d(s|c)?(\\s*(Plus|Pro))?))?)\\b"

   let regex: NSRegularExpression

   do {
        regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [.caseInsensitive, .useUnicodeWordBoundaries])
    }
    catch let error {
        fatalError("pattern ”\(pattern)” has an issue. \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    let range = NSMakeRange(0, input.count)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: input, range: range)
```

Currently the regex does capture no group. What I expect is it captures "iPhone XR" as the first group.

Here is a test bed: https://regex101.com/r/aHcyPQ/2

Comment: You should include in your question what you expect from input string to match and what it is currently matching.

Comment: I added what's expected and a link to see the regex in action +revo

Comment: There is some issue with your code, as `if let range = input.range(of: "(?i)\\b(iPhones?(\\s*(se|X((s(\\s*Max)?)|r)?|\\d(s|c)?(\\s*(Plus|Pro))?))?)\\b", options: .regularExpression) {
        let result = input.substring(with:range)
        print(result)
}` works.

Comment: I see, the issue is with `.useUnicodeWordBoundaries`. Remove it.

Comment: +Wiktor Stribiezw: thanks, you're right! I guess .useUnicodeWordBoundaries ONLY consider unicode word boundaries. Write the answer so that I credit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.useUnicodeWordBoundaries` enables the [`UREGEX_UWORD`](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp#TOC-Flag-Options) option:

> Controls the behavior of `\b` in a pattern. If set, word boundaries are found according to the definitions of word found in Unicode UAX 29, Text Boundaries. By default, word boundaries are identified by means of a simple classification of characters as either “word” or “non-word”, which approximates traditional regular expression behavior. The results obtained with the two options can be quite different in runs of spaces and other non-word characters.

The [Unicode UAX 29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/tr29-4.html) document describes these word boundaries in details and provides some nice illustrations.

The `’` is categorized as a MidLetter char:

> MidLetter  `Any of the following:`
>                   `U+0027 (') APOSTROPHE`
>                   `U+00B7 (·) MIDDLE DOT`
>                   `U+05F4 (״) HEBREW PUNCTUATION GERSHAYIM`
>                   `U+2019 (’) RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (curly apostrophe)`
>                   `U+2027 (‧) HYPHENATION POINT`

[image]

So, there is no Unicode word boundary between `L` and `i` in `L’iPhone`, remove `.useUnicodeWordBoundaries`.

Comment: That's quite odd in French, as for me, the apostrophe is clearly a word boundary to the contrary of the English.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca The point is that the apostrophe is between two letters. Regex is not natural language aware.